# Reversing (inverting) 32 bit unsigned int bit digits

Tags: c, bit

I'm trying to reverse unsigned int of 32 bit, want to turn zeros to ones, and ones to zeros, but seems there is something wrong.

input: 3

output: 4294967292

expected output: 2147483648

```
int main() {

    unsigned int n;
    scanf("%u",&n);

    n^=4294967295;
    printf("%u",n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output do you get and what output do you expect ?

Comment: "seems there is something wrong" -- What exactly? What's your input? What's the actual and the expected output? (In order to see whether your code works, you could print the binary representation before and after xoring `n`. Or maybe the hexadecimal values.)

Comment: And why do you expect `2147483648 (0x80000000)` ? The correct output is `4294967292 (0xfffffffc)`. Your expectation is wrong.

Comment: I would prefer the less obfuscated `n = ~n;`.

Comment: @molbdnilo or `n ^= 0xffffffff`.

Comment: This is more typically called "inverting", since "reversing" typically means "turning backwards", i.e. turning `0x80000000` to `0x00000001`. At least in my experience.

Comment: Try printing the hex values, it's usually easier when you're dealing with bit patterns. So `%08x` instead of `%u`.

Comment: @YasserMohamed You misinterpreted the sample input in [the assignment](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/flipping-bits). `3` is not one of the integers that needs to be bit-flipped; it's the list size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong.

Let's do everything in hexadecimal:

```
0x00000003 ^ 0xffffffff = 0xfffffffc
```

The correct output in hexadecimal is therefore `0xfffffffc` which is `4294967292` in (unsigned) decimal.

Or in binary:

```
  00000000000000000000000000000011    0x00000003
^ 11111111111111111111111111111111    0xffffffff
----------------------------------    ----------
  11111111111111111111111111111100    0xfffffffc
```

Comment: Wonder why you didn't use Integer to string and value of with radix 2 ?   Or commit subtraction of the value of on the 4 byte ceiling.(having not done a test case bit flip on a single byte expanded pen and paper) trying to make b64? or alike?