# Reverse a 32 bit integer in java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

I am solving the question on reversing the bits of a 32 Bit Integer in Java and below is the code for the same:

```
public class Solution {
    public static long reverseBits(long n) {
        int f=31;
        int l=0;
        int rev=0;
        while(f>l){
             if((n&(1<<f))!=0){
               rev=rev|(1<<l);
             }
             if((n&(1<<l))!=0){
               rev=rev|(1<<f);
             }
             f--;
             l++;
        }
           return rev;
    }
}
```

But the output is not the same as observed in the test case :

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tha2d.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY0eH.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reversing 32 bit unsigned int bit digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41694130/reversing-32-bit-unsigned-int-bit-digits)

Comment: The link to the Question is : https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/problems/reverse-bits_2181102?utm_source=striver&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=a_zcoursetuf&leftPanelTab=0

Comment: Your 'output' sample has an errant extra newline in it which then causes 2 entries to fail even though the numbers are otherwise identical. This code snippet does not include this errant newline, therefore, 'why does this code fail the test case' is not answerable, given that in large part its due to code beyond what you pasted. Edit the question and include your _actual_ code. All of it.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#reverse(int) ?

Comment: @RituparnaWarwatkar: although the asker says 'reversing' in #41694130, it is actually about inverting aka complementing not reversing, thus not a dupe.

Comment: Edited the question with the complete code

Comment: Your problem is that Java `int` (as well as `long short byte`) is _signed_ so you actually compute reverse(3) correctly as the bit pattern corresponding to 0xC0000000 (if that were legal in Java) but Java treats it as -0x40000000 or -1073741824. With return type `long` Java sign-extends; try instead `return rev & 0xFFFFFFFFL`.

Comment: @LakshyaGupta Did any of these answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.  Use a long to avoid getting a negative number if the sign high order bit of an `int` would be set.

- the first loop iterates thru the data set.
- the inner loop interates `32` times to fully reverse all `32` bits of the integer.
- shift the reversed value left one bit
- then AND the low order bit with `1` to get the low order bit's value.
- then OR the reversed value with that bit.
- then shift the input value right `1` bit to expose the next bit.

```
for (int d : data) {
    long reversed = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        reversed = (reversed<<1)|(d&1);
        d>>=1;
    }
    System.out.println(reversed);
}
```

prints

```
536870912
1610612736
1342177280
3221225472
```